# Symfony 3 working with multiple databases

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to create a REST API that uses multiple databases. I need to connect to a database from the value comes from token. I can't define all databases in config.yml and parameters.yml because new databases may be added. I want it to be complete dynamic . I tryied something like below.

```
$connection = $this->container->get('doctrine.dbal.default_connection');

$refConn = new \ReflectionObject($connection);
$refParams = $refConn->getProperty('_params');
$refParams->setAccessible('public'); 


$params = $refParams->getValue($connection);
$params['dbname'] = $domain;

$refParams->setAccessible('private');
$refParams->setValue($connection, $params);

$this->container->get('doctrine')->resetManager('default');

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');
```

When I "dump($em);" it shows me the database that I want to connect but when I perform a SQL query it returns the default database's data.

Is anyone did something like this? I would be grateful for help.

This is the complete code snippet. I do not set up the token environment yet, but for now I send it from headers.

```
public function getUploadsAction ($Request request)
{
$ domain = $ request -> headers -> get ('domain');

$ connection = $ this-> container-> get ('doctrine.dbal.default_connection');

$ refConn = new \ ReflectionObject ($connection);
$ refParams = $ refConn-> getProperty ('_ params');
$ RefParams-> setAccessible ('public');

$ params = $ refParams-> getValue ($ connection);
$ params ['dbname'] = $ domain;

$ refParams-> setAccessible ('private');
$ refParams-> setValue ($ connection, $ params);

$ $this->container->get ('doctrine') -> resetManager ('default');

$ em = $ this-> getDoctrine () -> getManager ('default');

$ sql = 'SELECT * upload WHERE RECNO ='. $ request-> headers-> get ('recno');
$ statement = $ em-> getConnection () -> prepare ($ sql);
$ statement->execute();
$ result = $statement->fetchAll();

return $result;

}
```

Comment: please show the complete code when you are trying to perform the SQL query